# how to close a project in tizen studio?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I have been working in tizen studio for Gear s2 web app. 
I have opened many projects in project explorer, but there in no close option 
available when I right click on a project in project explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I think SDK developer miss the `close project` at context popup menu.

Use Project menu on top.

Select projects and click the `Project` - `Close Project`

Comment: This command just collapse the project, nothing else. It does not close the project

Comment: No, It actually close the project. For example, Closed projects will not build at Build All command. and also it should be excluded when search somthing in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

As of Tizen Studio 1.0, there is no "Close project" option in Project Explorer context menu. So, one can either close a project using top Project menu (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39607790/1893766)) or add a custom key binding.

To add a custom key binding

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
2. Scroll down to or type "Close Project" in search field
3. Put the cursor to "Binding:" input field
4. Press the preferred key combinations to close a project, e.g.,
   <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>

Now you can close projects by selecting them in Project Explorer and pressing the chosen keys. Hope this helps.

[image: Tizen Studio 1.0. Preferences Window]

Comment: It just collapse the project. it stills shows in project explorer.

Answer (score -1):

Try selecting project(s) from Project Explorer and press delete button.
You will get a pop up named "Delete Resources". Then press "Ok".

[image]